# How to use Sparse Columns in a Dynamic SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I have used the below DYNAMIC SQL SCRIPT to convert a table like

> (1,AttributeName1,Attributevalue1)
>   (1,AttributeName2,Attributevalue2)
>   (2,AttributeName1,Attributevalue1)
>   (2,AttributeName2,Attributevalue2)
>  .
>  .
>  .
>   (11113,AttributeName2,Attributevalue2)

TO A table into below format

> (Datapoint,AttributeName1,AttributeName2,.............AttributeNamen)
>   (1,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)
>    (2,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)
> .
> .
> .
>   (11113,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)

==============DYNAMIC SQL SCRIPT================

```
SET @sql = NULL;<br/>
SELECT<br/>
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT<br/>
    CONCAT(<br/>
      'max(CASE WHEN AttributeName = ''',<br/>
      AttributeName,<br/>
      ''' THEN AttributeValue END) AS `',
      AttributeName, '`'<br/>
    )<br/>
  ) INTO @sql<br/>
FROM yourtable;<br/>
<br/>

SET @sql <br/>
  = CONCAT('SELECT datapoint, ', @sql, ' <br/>
           from yourtable<br/>
           group by datapoint');<br/>

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;<br/>
EXECUTE stmt;<br/>
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;<br/>
```

PROBLEM: I am running out of SQL number of columns limit.I know that I have to use SPARSE columns(because my table has a lot of NULL values).

Any idea how to you SPARSE columns in above SQL script?

Comment: @bluefeet  Can you please have a look at this?

Comment: Why dont you use Attribute names as records in a metadata table, and use the key in your value table?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I recommend fetching all the data as it is organized in the database, and postprocess the result into PHP hash arrays.  Here's a pseudocode example, but I don't know which PHP API for MySQL you use:

```
$sql = "SELECT datapoint, AttributeName, AttributeValue FROM yourtable";

/* execute $sql */

$data = array();
while (/* $row = fetch one row */) {
  $data[$row["datapoint"]][$row["AttributeName"]] = $row["AttributeValue"];
}
```

Now you have an array $data of hash arrays for your sparse data.

---

Re your comment:

Okay, fair enough.  If you're trying to do this in MySQL only, my suggestion above isn't relevant.

You're probably running into a limit on the length of a string produced by GROUP_CONCAT().  The default limit of a group-concat string is 1024 bytes.  Your columns are long expressions, at least characters each.  So you can have at most 15 of these expressions in one group-concat string.

That group-concat string length limit is configurable by the variable [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).  You can configure it up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or 2<sup>64</sup>-1 bytes.

```
mysql> SET group_concat_max_len = 1024*1024*1024; /* 1GB */
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...) ... INTO @sql;
```

Then when you prepare that @sql string into a query, it will have many columns, but IIRC the limit on columns in a query is 4096.  I'd be surprised if you are exceeding that.

Comment: We aren't using PHP. We are trying to execute the program in MySQL.